# Remove duplicate rows based on a column values by storing the row whose entry in another column is maximum

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following matrix

```
> mat<-rbind(c(9,6),c(10,6),c(11,7),c(12,7),c(12,8),c(12,9),c(12,10),c(12,11),c(12,12),c(13,12))
> mat
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]     9    6
[2,]    10    6
[3,]    11    7
[4,]    12    7
[5,]    12    8
[6,]    12    9
[7,]    12   10
[8,]    12   11
[9,]    12   12
[10,]   13   12
```

I would like to remove duplicate rows based on first column values and store the row whose entry in the second column is maximum. E.g. for the example above, the desidered outcome is

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]     9    6
[2,]    10    6
[3,]    11    7
[4,]    12   12
[5,]    13   12
```

I tried with

```
> mat[!duplicated(mat[,1]),]
```

but I obtained

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9    6
[2,]   10    6
[3,]   11    7
[4,]   12    7
[5,]   13   12
```

which is different from the desidered outcome for the entry [4,2]. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the matrix first, using ascending order for column 1 and descending order for column 2. Then the duplicated function will remove all but the maximum column 2 value for each column 1 value.

```
mat <- mat[order(mat[,1],-mat[,2]),]

mat[!duplicated(mat[,1]),]

         [,1] [,2]
    [1,]    9    6
    [2,]   10    6
    [3,]   11    7
    [4,]   12   12
    [5,]   13   12
```

Comment: Very clean logic. Very nice solution. Just one suggestion .. In the second line perhaps you want to assign the results to something . may be mat itself.

Comment: Thanks! I considered that but decided to mimic the code of the original poster, who printed rather than assigned the results of the matrix with duplicate column 1 values removed.

Answer (score 1):

Like Josephs solution, but if you add row names first you can keep the original order (which will be the same in this case).

```
rownames(mat) <- 1:nrow(mat)

mat <- mat[order(mat[,2], -mat[,2]),]

mat <- mat[!duplicated(mat[,1]),]
mat[order(as.numeric(rownames(mat))),]
#   [,1] [,2]
# 1    9    6
# 2   10    6
# 3   11    7
# 4   12   12
# 5   13   12
```

Answer (score 1):

First Sort then keep only the first row for each duplicate

```
mat <- mat[order(mat[,1], mat[,2]),]
mat[!duplicated(mat[,1]),]
```

EDIT: Sorry I thought your desired result is last df,Ok so you want max value

```
mat<-rbind(c(9,6),c(10,6),c(11,7),c(12,7),c(12,8),c(12,9),c(12,10),c(12,11),c(12,12),c(13,12))

#Reverse sort
mat <- mat[order(mat[,1], mat[,2], decreasing=TRUE),]
#Keep only the first row for each duplicate, this will give the largest values
mat <- mat[!duplicated(mat[,1]),]
#finally sort it
mat <- mat[order(mat[,1], mat[,2]),]
```